# replace character if repeated in line below

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following sequence,

```
N
H
CB
CB
CG1
CG2
C
O
N
H
CB
CB
CG
CD
.
.
.
```

and I would like to replace the first "CB" with "CA" when "CB" is repeated in line below, so as to end up with the following sequence

```
N
H
CA
CB
CG1
CG2
C
O
N
H
CA
CB
CG
CD
.
.
.
```

Comment: If you were after the general case ("when the next line == the current line, decrement the current line") then be aware that the "what is predecessor of a string" is tricky. For example, what is the predecessor of "CG1"? Is is "CG0" or "CG" or something else?

Comment: `sed -E '$!N;s/^(CB)(\n\1)$/CA\2/' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing is a lot simpler to wrap your head around if you can read the file backwards.  Fortunately, `tac` (which is `cat` backwards because that's what it does) is there to let us do this.  We can then make a note when we see a "CB", and if we see "CB" on the next (formerly previous) line, edit it; then flip it back-to-front again with another use of `tac`:

```
$ tac input | awk '/CB/ && found==1 { $1="CA"; found=0 } /CB/ && found==0 { found=1 } ! /CB/ && found==1 { found=0 } {print}' | tac
N
H
CA
CB
CG1
CG2
C
O
N
H
CA
CB
CG
CD
```